# MongoDB Mongoose JS time series not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, time-series, nosql

I'm using NodeJS and Mongoose JS. I was trying to create user analytics by leveraging MongoDB time series on my project. I'm a new developer. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The database is not showing any changes.

I want to save the day to day user analytics in my time series.

My Mongoose Schema:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const User = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    analytics: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: [
        {
          date: new Date(),
          country: {},
          browser: {},
          os: {},
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    timeseries: {
      timeField: "createdAt",
      metaField: "email",
      granularity: "seconds",
    },
    expireAfterSeconds: 86400,
  }
);

export default model("User", User);
```

The output shows like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641b2811c93e3ca1ae196995"
  },
  "email": "email1@email.com",
  "name": "Name Name",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1679501306802"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1679501329465"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1679501356039"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to implement time series properly?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using MongoDB 5.0. You would need to create the TS collection using [`createCollection()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-createCollection) while disabling `autoIndex` in your schema.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        analytics: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
            default: [
                {
                    date: new Date(),
                    country: {},
                    browser: {},
                    os: {},
                },
            ],
        },

    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        autoIndex: false,
    },
);

const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


async function run() {

    await dropCollections();
    await UserModel.createCollection({
        timeseries: {
            timeField: "createdAt",
            metaField: "email",
            granularity: "seconds",
        },
        expireAfterSeconds: 86400,
    })
};

mongoose.connect(url)
    .then(async () => run())
    .catch(console.dir)
    .finally(() => {
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
```

I hope it helps!